# Dirac action momenta conjugate to conjugate field

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, fermions, dirac-equation, gauge-invariance, constrained-dynamics

Consider the Dirac action $S=\int d^4x\bar{\psi}(x)(i\not\partial-m)\psi(x)$. Since there are no time derivative of $\bar{\psi}$, we get the constraint that its canonical momenta vanishes. This constraint is of course first class. Does this mean that the Dirac equation has a gauge symmetry? Why do we usually not care about it when doing the canonical quantization of the Dirac field? Thanks!

Comment: If you think about the phase space as containing momenta associated to both $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$, then the two constraints mentioned below are $\bar{\pi} = 0 $ and $\pi - i\bar{\psi}\gamma^0= 0$. The Poisson bracket between the constraints is then proportional to the Poisson bracket between $\bar{\psi}$ and $\bar{\pi}$, and is therefore nonzero.

Comment: Got it! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are 2 [primary constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) rather than 1. (Recall that there is also 1  primary constraint for the complex conjugate field). The 2 primary constraints do not (super)Poisson-commute, so they are second-class rather than [first-class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint). And therefore no gauge symmetry. See e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/59443/2451).

Comment: I don't see the second primary constraint since the action does have time derivatives with respect to $\psi$. Funnily enough, I think that my confusion has to do with the question you linked. In particular, using the more symmetric action $\frac{i}{2}\bar{\psi}\not\partial\psi+\frac{i}{2}\bar{\psi}\overleftarrow{\not\partial}\psi+m\bar{\psi}\psi$ it is clear that both momenta do not vanish and we have the two second class primary constraints.