# Hamiltonian dependence of variables

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

How can one say that in Hamilton mechanics the $q$'s are independent of the $p$'s while if I have the Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2\dot{y}^2$  then  $p_y = \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial\dot{y}} = x^2\dot{y}$ and the $p_y$ depends on $x$?

Comment: I think there should be a duplicate in PSE somewhere, but I cannot find one at the moment. For the time being, think about what you are assuming: that an equals sign indicates dependence. This is certainly not always true. For example, Newton's second law tells us $F=ma$. Does this mean the net force acting on an object depends on its mass?

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119992/179151) is not a duplicate question, but I think the accepted answer will help you out a bit :)

Comment: If $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q _{i}}\neq f\left( q_{i}\right) $ then $\dot p_¡$ is independent of $q_¡$