# Hamilton-Jacobi equation with a second-order Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, action, phase-space

The [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is:
\begin{equation}
H\left(q,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q},t\right)+\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}~=~0,
\end{equation}
where $S$ is [Hamilton's principal function](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/HamiltonsPrincipalFunction.html).

If we take a second-order $L$ such that $$L=L(\{q_j,\dot{q}_j,\ddot{q}_j\},t),$$ does the Hamilton-Jacobi equation change, or we could always consider that $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-H~?$$

Comment: Which definition of the "Hamiltonian" are you using for higher-order Lagrangians? There are several (e.g. that by Ostrogradsky) that are similar, but not the same.

Comment: umm if it's true to consider that ∂S/∂t=−H, I would define my Hamiltonian from \delta S (wich is equal to L \delta t), so H will be =∑j p\dot{q}+∑j ∂S/∂\dot{q} \ddot{q}−L  (all will  j index)

Comment: @ACuriousMind am I allowed to write this? I've never worked with a higher-order L.

Comment: The point is - what space is that new $H$ living on? In the first-order setting, we switch from the Lagrangian tangent bundle with coordinates $(q,\dot{q})$ to the Hamiltonian phase space/cotangent bundle with coordinates $(q,p)$. But here you can't just Legendre transform the $\dot{q}$, you need to somehow handle the $\ddot{q}$ dependence. There are difference schemes for that, leading to different notions of the final Hamiltonian, so it's not exactly clear what you want to do here.

Comment: What I've written in my comment is absolutely wrong :) I'm sorry! So I've decided to use the Ostogradsky Hamiltonian. But I still don't know if the Hamilton-jacobi equation is still true anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let us suppress explicit time dependence $t$ from the notation in the following. Let there be given a second-order Lagrangian
   $$L(q,v,a); \tag{1}$$
   where $q^i$ are positions, $v^i$ are velocities, $a^i$ are accelerations, and where $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
2. We would like to find the corresponding [Ostrogradsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability) Hamiltonian formulation. Let us for simplicity assume that the Hessian
   $$ H_{ij}~=~\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial a^i\partial a^j} \tag{2}$$
   is invertible.$^1$ Then the Ostrogradsky Hamiltonian is defined as
   $$ H(Q,P)~:=~ p_iv^i + \sup_a\left(\pi_i a^i-L(q,v,a)\right) ,\tag{3}$$
   where we have introduced the collective notation
   $$Q^I~=~\{q^i;v^i\},\qquad  P_I~=~\{p_i;\pi_i\},\qquad 
   I~\in~\{1,\ldots,2n\}.\tag{4} $$
3. In the spirit of my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106611/2451), we introduce an extended Lagrangian$^2$
   $$ L_E(Q,\dot{Q},P,a)~:=~p_i(\dot{q}^i-v^i)+\pi_i(\dot{v}^i-a^i)+L(q,v,a).\tag{5}$$
   If we integrate out $P_I$, $v^i$ and $a^i$ in the extended Lagrangian (5), we get back the Lagrangian itself
   $$ L(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q})\tag{6} .$$
   If we only integrate out $a^i$ in the extended Lagrangian (5), we get the Ostrogradsky Hamiltonian Lagrangian
   $$ L_H(Q,\dot{Q},P)~:=~P_I\dot{Q}^I - H(Q,P).\tag{7}$$
   This implies that the higher-order Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations of (5) is equivalent to a standard [Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) in $Q^I$ and $P_I$! In other words, in the non-singular case (2), we can re-use the standard [Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) for this case! The only difference is that the phase space (4) is twice as big.

--

$^1$ If the Hessian matrix is singular, there will appear [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_%28classical_mechanics%29), and the Hamiltonian formulation and the Hamilton-Jacobi theory become modified as a result.

$^2$ If we vary  the extended Lagrangian (5) wrt. to $a^i$ and $v^i$, we get the [Ostrogradsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability) momenta
$$ \pi_i~\approx~\frac{\partial L}{\partial a^i} ,\tag{8} $$
and
$$ p_i ~\approx~\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^i}- \dot{\pi}_i~\approx~\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^i}- \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial a^i} ,\tag{9} $$
respectively. [The $\approx$ sign means equality modulo equations of motion.]