# Is this action a Hamilton's principal function?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, action, constrained-dynamics

In Ref. 1, in section 3, they wrote:
\begin{equation}
L'(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},t)~=~L(q,\dot{q},\ddot{q},t)-\frac{dS(q,\dot{q},t)}{dt}.\tag{14}
\end{equation}
Then the Hamilton-Jacobi equation is 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}~=~-H_0,\tag{27}
\end{equation}
where $$H_0~=~p\dot{q}+\pi\ddot{q}-L,\tag{28}$$ where 
$$p~=~\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial q}\quad\text{and}\quad
\pi~=~\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial \dot{q}}.\tag{29}$$

I was confused because here the action is a function of $\dot{q}$ ! Then I read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32277/127427) answer by Qmechanic, and I had **this question**: is this action a Hamilton's principle function? If yes, in Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$, the $\alpha$ is an integration constant. But here we have $S(q,\dot{q},t)$;  $\dot{q}$ is not an integration constant. If no, what is that action?

*EDIT*: I want to know if the function $S$ is considered as an action. If yes, I need an explanation on how an action could be a function of $\dot{q}$? And if no, how is this function related to the known action $S[q]$?

References:

1. B.M. Pimentel & R.G. Teixeira, *Hamilton-Jacobi formulation for singular systems with second order Lagrangians,* [arXiv:hep-th/9512099](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9512099).

Comment: The Lagrangian is almost never written in terms of $ \ddot{q} $ or anything higher.

Comment: @QuantumFool  _"almost" never_ , but not in my research case, where I'm interested in higher order derivatives Lagrangian.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283166/2451

Comment: This could be an answer for that post if S is the action.. but I don't know if S is the action or just a function. If it's not the action, then this is not the answer for the question in the other post.

Comment: If it's not the action, there should be a relation between the S and the action of course.. they're not totally different

Answer (score 1):

OP is asking about Ref. 1. This touches upon several topics:

1. Second-order Lagrangian formulations and their corresponding [Ostrogradsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability) Hamiltonian formulation. This is discussed in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283166/2451) Phys.SE post, where it is explained how to reduce to first-order formulation in the non-singular case.
2. Singular Legendre transformations, and constraints. See e.g. Ref. 2 & 3.
3. Caratheodory’s method of equivalent Lagrangians, and its connection to [Hamilton-Jacobi theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation). This is explained in Ref. 4 in the first-order case.

Now let us return to OP's title question. Let us stress that the [Hamilton's principal function](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/HamiltonsPrincipalFunction.html) $S$ and the [off-shell action functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_%28physics%29#Action_.28functional.29) $S[q]$ are different objects. (For first-order Lagrangians, this is e.g. explained in my Phys.SE answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32277/2451) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90857/2451).) In particular, eq. (14) is part of Caratheodory’s method of equivalent Lagrangians. The $S$ appearing in eq. (14) is Hamilton's principal function, not the off-shell action functional. It depends on velocities because the theory is of second order.

References:

1. B.M. Pimentel & R.G. Teixeira, *Hamilton-Jacobi formulation for singular systems with second order Lagrangians,* [arXiv:hep-th/9512099](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9512099).
2. P.A.M. Dirac, *Lectures on QM,* (1964).
3. M. Henneaux and C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.
4. H.A. Kastrup, [*Canonical theories of Lagrangian dynamical systems in physics*](http://www.desy.de/~hkastrup/reprints/Phys.Rep.101%281983%291-167%20%28Canonical%20theories%29.pdf), [Phys. Rep. 101 (1983) 1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(83)90037-6); Section 2.4.

Comment: Alright, but now I'm confused. 1. why do we use the off-shell action to determine the equations of motion instead of the on-shell one? 2. Doesn't "on/off-shell" determine whether any term satisfies the e.o.m or not? 3. Also when do we use the on-shell action instead of the off-shell one? 4. Is that only related to higher order derivative Lagrangians? 5. or does it have a connection with virtual or unknown paths?

Comment: 1. One needs the eoms to construct the on-shell action in the first place. 2. Yes. 3. Too broad question. 4. No. 5. Off-shell action also applies to virtual paths.