# Confusion on Hamiltonian unbounded from below and Ostrogradsky Instability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian, unitarity, ground-state

This might be a silly question but I failed to get it. In [Ostrogradsky Instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability), we deduced that Lagrangian of higher-order derivatives leads to Hamiltonian linear to canonical momenta, and thus, Hamiltonian is unbounded from below. However, a particle in potential: $V(r)=-\frac{1}{r}$ also has a Hamiltonian unbounded from below as $r$ approaches to zero, so why doesn’t it lead to an instability similar to Ostrogradsky instability? What makes them different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is important is that the [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)) of the Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$ is bounded from below, and that it has a ground state; not that the classical Hamiltonian $H$ is bounded from below in the classical phase space. E.g. quantum mechanically the [hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom) has a ground state despite the Coulomb potential is unbounded from below.

Comment: However, could spectrum be bounded from below, if $\hat{H}$ was linear in $\hat{p}$?

Comment: Yes, e.g. if the phase space is compact.

Comment: Any concrete example?

Comment: @JánLalinský a proof is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.11538) on page 9, but perhaps it is not satisfactory.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks a lot, the answer is very helpful. But something else confuses me: what is the physical interpretation of Ostrogradskian Hamiltonian in the simplest system(after choosing $Q_{1}=q, P_{1}= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} -\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot{q} } ,Q_{2}=\dot{q}, P_{2}= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \ddot q} $) or why does it make sense to regard it as the total energy of the system?

Comment: Hi @Aimikan. Thanks for the feedback. You might have a look at e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283166/2451) related Phys.SE post.