# Can we also Legendre transform the Lagrangian using $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$ instead of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

We calculate the Hamiltonian as the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian
$$H(q,p,t) = p \dot q - L(q,\dot q,t), $$
where $p$ is the slope function
$$p \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} .$$

The general idea of the Legendre transform is that we replace our function $f(x)$, depending on some variable $x$, with a new function $F(s)$ that only depends on the slope $$s(x) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial  x} $$ which, however, contains the same information.

For a function which depends on multiple variables $g(x,y,z,\ldots)$ we can do this for any of the variables and generate this way different Legendre transforms.

Therefore, I was wondering if it also makes sense to consider the alternative Legendre transform of the Lagrangian
$$G(s,\dot q,t) = s  q - L(q,\dot q,t), $$
where $s$ is the slope function
$$s \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial  q} .$$
If yes, what's the name of this alternative Legendre transform? And if not, why does it make sense to consider the Legendre transform with respect to $\dot q$ but not with respect to $q$?

---

PS: I found a related idea in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5510) but they consider Legendre transforms involving $ \dot p \equiv \frac{\partial H}{\partial  q} .$

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Why do we use the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian instead of other related functions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455135/2451)

Comment: @Qmechanic so, in principle, it's possible and $f \equiv \dot p \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial  q} $, where $f$ denotes the force. But for most systems, the corresponding Legendre transform is ill-defined because there is no bijective relation between position $q$ and force $f$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Correct.