# Are Hamilton’s equations time-independent from it’s general derivation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, hamiltonian-formalism

The general derivation of Hamilton’s equations involve the change in the Hamiltonian and consequently the change in the Lagrangian that is a function of $q$ and $\dot q$, $L(q,\dot q)$. This is shown in this simple video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXu6zIItnLM

When deriving Hamilton’s equations for $\dot q$ and $\dot p$, the Lagrangian is only a function of $q$ and $\dot q$ but not time. Therefore the Lagrangian used to derive Hamilton’s equations is time-independent as it appears. Does that means that Hamilton’s equations for $\dot q$ and $\dot p$ are only right for systems for which the Lagrangian is time-independent (and therefore the Hamiltonian - or energy is conserved)?

Comment: The premise of this post (v2) is wrong: A general Lagrangian could have explicit time dependence.

Comment: And the derivation will give the exact same result?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451 and links therein.