# Conditions to perform Legendre transformation of lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Let $\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{q}, \dot{\boldsymbol{q}},t)$ be the lagrangian of a certain system with $n$ degrees of freedom. By definition of Legendre transformation (not Legendre-Fenchel) the lagrangian hessian matrix with respect to generalized velocities:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}^i\partial\dot{q}^j}\right)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

has to be positive definite. If the lagrangian is of the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=T-U
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is a generalized potential, it can be proved that for a mechanical system $(1)$ is positive definite (it's the matrix of the quadratic form associated to $T$). On the other hand, I've seen some only require that
\begin{equation}
\det\left(\frac{\partial^2\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}^i\partial\dot{q}^j}\right)\neq0
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
(non degenerate lagrangian) that means that the system:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q^j}}=p_j\qquad j=1...n
\end{equation}

is invertible. This condition is necessary, though, it does not guarantee $(1)$ to be positive definite and thus the requirements of legendre transformation. So why is $(3)$  in some context used as a condition to perform the Legendre transform of the lagrangian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's 2 different conditions arise from using 2 different definitions of the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation). One definition uses supremum while another definition uses substitution, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/339405/2451).

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using the latter (the one without supremum). Using this definition and requiring the invertibility condition, we can define a Hamiltonian but, as you said: _"Finally, we should mentioned that even if we can mathematically define the Legendre transform H(p), there is no guarantee that it makes sense physically."_