# Apply the Heisenberg Equation to the Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, commutator, hamiltonian

$\frac{d}{dt}$$\hat{H}$ = $\frac{i}{\hbar}$$[\hat{H},\hat{H}]$ +$\frac{\partial{\hat{H}}}{\partial{t}}$

That's as far as I've got. I do not know much about the Heisenberg equation or even what it represents. Could someone give me a beginners intro to it ?

I do have one idea : $\hat{H}$ = $i\hbar$$\frac{d}{dt}$

I've been told that if there is no time dependence then $\frac{\partial{\hat{H}}}{\partial{t}}$ in the Heisenberg equation goes to 0.

I am not sure if the Hamiltonian has no time dependence because of that derivative wrt to time in the above equation.

Secondly, even if I could prove $\frac{\partial{\hat{H}}}{\partial{t}}$ = 0 I have absolutely no idea whatsoever what  $\frac{i}{\hbar}$$[\hat{H},\hat{H}]$ means. I have no clue how to evaluate it or what its significance is.

Comment: The square brackets denote the [commutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator). $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=\hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A}$ is a measure for the difference between letting $\hat{B}$ *then* $\hat{A}$ operate and letting $\hat{A}$ *then* $\hat{B}$ operate. For operators, you usually calculate the commutator by letting the whole thing operate on a function: $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]\Psi$. But if $\hat{A} = \hat{B}$ it's clear that the commutator is zero, even without explicitly calculating it.

Comment: Concerning the time dependence: the Hamiltonian is the [Legendre transform](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/physical-meaning-of-legendre-transformation/69374#69374) of the Lagrangian. So if the Lagrangian has no explicit time-dependence, so does the Hamiltonian. [Usually](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11905/16660) we can also identify the Hamiltonian (actually its eigenvalues) with the total energy of the system and the absence of an explicit time dependence corresponds to energy conservation.

Comment: If my comments answered your question, let me know. Then I'll convert them into an actual answer - which I just realized they sort of are (so they shouldn't really be comments either way).

Answer (score 5):

First, a note about the Hamiltonian and its time derivatives. I think that it is misleading to write that the Hamiltonian
$$
H = i\hbar\frac{d}{dt},
$$
although the time-dependent Schrodinger equation is of course
$$
H\psi = i\hbar\frac{d}{dt} \psi.
$$

To evaluate e.g. $\frac{d}{dt}H$ you should consider $H=H(p, q, t)$, rather than $H = i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}$. $p$ and $q$ are the [canonical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates) in the [Legendre transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/physical-meaning-of-legendre-transformation/69374#69374) between the Hamiltonian and the Lagrangian formalisms.

The [commutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator) is defined,
$$
[A,B]=AB-BA,
$$
so $[H,H]=0$ and we have 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}H = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}H
$$
*The full time derivative of $H$ is equal to the partial time derivative of $H$. What does this mean? It means that Heisenberg's equation is related to Hamilton's equations!*

To see this, write the full derivative as
$$
\frac{d}{dt} H = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \dot q + \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \dot p + \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}
$$
We must have 
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \dot q + \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \dot p = 0
$$
This is satisfied by Hamilton's equations,
$$
\dot q = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\\
\dot p = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}
$$

Comment: By canonical coordinates do you mean x and y ?