# Probabilistic Intuition behind connected correlations and 1PI vertex function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, probability, 1pi-effective-action

In the context of statistical field or quantum field theory, one encounters so called generating function(al) for connected correlations, aka the following function(al):

$$ W(J) = \ln (Z(J))$$

$$ Z(J) = \int \mathcal{D} \phi   e^{-S[\phi]}$$

From a probabilistic standpoint, Z(J) is just the moment generating function(al) while $\ln Z$ is the cumulant generating function(al), I think one generates $\langle \phi^2 \rangle$ for example and the other generates $\langle (\phi - \langle \phi \rangle)^2 \rangle$.

However, we further define another generating function(al), call $\Gamma(\phi)$ usually called the "Effective Action" defined via legendre transform of the function(al) $W(J)$.

1. Why is $\Gamma[\phi]$ the effective action a useful quantity to calculate?
2. What is the probabilistic interpretation of the 1PI diagrams it generates? (cumulant, variance etc...).
3. If correlation functions tell me how lab measurements of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ at space/time points x/y would correlate, what do the 1PI functions generated by $\Gamma$ physically represent?
4. Bonus question!  The convex nature of the functional W(J) (the fact the Hessian $${\delta^2 \over \delta J(x) \delta J(y)} W(J) > 0 \forall x, y$$) ensures that the legendre transform is bijective.  How do we motive this fact physically?  Are there cases when this is not true and the effective action is no longer a useful quantity?

Any discussion of the intuition about the quantity $\Gamma[\phi]$ would help, even if it is in the lower dimensional case where $\phi$ is not a field but a single random variable for example.

Comment: If you notice I've included the term function(al) because I believe this theory can be treated both in the continuum and discrete case. In one case $\phi$ is a statistical/quantum field, and in the second case,  $\phi$ as a single random variable.  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Post (v2) discussed in the chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38410796#38410796).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In probability theory $W=\log Z$ is called the generating function for [cumulants](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144773/what-is-a-cumulant-really). Its [Legendre-Fenchel transform](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176239/legendre-transformation-non-convex-non-convave-functions) $\Gamma$ is the rate function appearing in theorems on large deviations such as [Cramer's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory#Large_deviations_for_sums_of_independent_random_variables). I think if you want more information about the probabilistic meaning of $\Gamma$, then you should lookup the literature on the theory of large deviations. A classic book on the subject is "Large Deviations Techniques and Applications" by Dembo and Zeitouni. A nice introduction with emphasis on statistical mechanics is "A Course on Large Deviations with an Introduction to Gibbs Measures" by Rassoul-Agha and Seppäläinen.

Answer (score 2):

Replace in your formula $S,W,\Gamma$ by the same letters divided by the Boltzmann constant $k$ (the probabilistic analogue of Planck's constant $\hbar$). Then, in the limit of $k\to 0$, the effective action becomes the original action, $\Gamma=S+O( k)$. Thus the effective action is the low temperature (in statistical mechanics ) resp. semiclassical (in quantum field theory) analogue of the (zero temperature, resp. classical) action, and can be determined by an expansion in terms of $k$. As it contains all information about the probability distribution, it is a very useful quantity.