# Is there a physical connection between Lagrangian mechanics and Hamilton mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I know that the Hamilton's equations results from the Legendre transformation of the Lagrange equation. 
It's also well-known that the Hamiltonian is equal to the energy of a system if the system is time independent but that is caused by the symmetry of $H$, not because of  the fact that the Lagrange function is given by the kinetic energy plus the potential energy.
So is there a concret physical relationship between $H$ and $L$?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4384/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451 and links therein.