# What exactly is the Legendre transformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

Goldstein et al's Classical Mechanics states that:

> The Hamiltonian $H(q,p,t)$ is generated by the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation)
>   $$ H(q,p,t) = \dot{q}_i p_i - L(q,\dot{q},t). \tag{8.15} $$

But I don't see how this equation even makes sense: $\dot q_i$, or $\dot q$ doesn't appear in the arguments of $H(q,p,t)$. In order to know $\dot q$, one would have to know not the value of $q$ but the entire function $q(t)$, and as far as I understand, $H$ is a function of the *values* of $q$ at a particular point in time, not the entire path over time.

This makes me doubt whether I understand what this equation means, or what the Legendre transform is.

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/307805/50583) may be of use to you

Comment: Possible duplicates:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4384/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/307794/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [A mathematically illogical argument in the derivation of Hamilton's equation in Goldstein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477111/)