# Differentiate the Lagrangian wrt. momentum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, differentiation

Given
$$
L=L(t, x_i, \dot x_i)
$$
as a function of generalized coordinates/velocity, and
$$
p_i:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x_i},
$$
how can we calculate
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i}?$$

Comment: Presumably by thinking of $\dot{x}$ as a function of $p$. Is this from a textbook? How did you encounter this?

Comment: It's not from a textbook (someone edit and add "homework" I kept it).
I need that in general inside the formalism of Lagrangian mechanics.
How having $\dot{x}(p)$ helps?

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial p_i}=0$ by the same reasoning that  $\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial \dot{x}_i}=0$, see [A mathematically illogical argument in the derivation of Hamilton's equation in Goldstein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477111/a-mathematically-illogical-argument-in-the-derivation-of-hamiltons-equation-in/477873#477873).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the exact answer depends on the context where you found this.

But mathematically, this could be done with the chain rule:
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_i} \frac{\partial \dot{x}_i}{\partial p_i}. $$

Then, as suggested in the comment, you'd have to work out $\dot{x}_i(p_i)$ in order to compute $\partial \dot{x}_i/\partial p_i$.

A possible application of this is comuting the Hamiltonian $H(x_i, p_i)$ from the Lagrangian $L(x_i, \dot{x}_i)$. 
 In (classical) electromagnetism you know that the conjugate momentum $p_i$ ( $= \partial L/\partial \dot{x}_i$ ) $= \gamma m_0 \dot{x}_i$, i.e. $p_i(\dot{x}_i)$.

You can just invert this by writing $\dot{x}_i = p_i/(\gamma m_0)$, i.e. $\dot{x}_i(p_i)$.
 This allows you to find the Hamiltonian $H = p_i \dot{x}_i - L = \gamma m_0 c^2$.

Comment: This is a situation where the partial derivatives need to specify which variables are being held constant while the differentiation is done—because there are more variables than underlying degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Buzz Good point. Should I treat $\dot{x}_i$ and $p_i$ on equal footing? That is, whatever is held constant with respect to one is also held constant with respect to the other?

Answer (score 1):

@SuperCiocia:
The context is what you mention. Expressing Hamilton Equations only related to Lagrangian, generalized coordinated/velocity, it is not applied to a specific dynamical system, it's general.

Particulary this one
$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}=\dot{x_i}$

If my math are correct we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i} & = \frac{\partial \sum{\dot{x_k}p_k} - L}{\partial p_i} = \dot{x_i} \\
 & = \sum{\frac{\partial \dot{x_k}p_k}{\partial p_i}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} \\ 
 & = \sum{\dot{x_k}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} (??? NotSure) \\
 & = \dot{x_i} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} (Or ??? NotSure) \\
\end{align}
$$

What should give us:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i}=\sum{\dot{x_k}}-\dot{x_i}
$$
Or
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i}=0
$$
As mentionned by @Frobenius

If it's correct didn't help to express $\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}=\dot{x_i}$ only in function of term $(t, x_i, \dot{x_i}, L)$.