# Invertibility of the Legendre Transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

[image: Legendre Transformation]

The above image shows the Legendre Transformation in the context of an introduction to the Hamiltonian formalism.

My question is in 4.6, wherein $u(x, y)$ has been defined; **what is the guarantee that we would be able to invert this relation in order to get $x(u, y)$?** Or in other words, what is the guarantee that we would be able to write $\dot{q_{i}}$ as $\dot{q_{i}}(p_{i}, q_{i}, t)?$. And doesn't that affect the invertibility of the Legendre transformation as a whole as written in the lines following equation 4.9?

Another question: **Is time supposed to be a spectator variable** when it comes to a Legendre Transformation in Hamiltonian dynamics?

Could somebody possibly dwell on this rigorously? Thanks.

Comment: Please write equations yourself, rather than posting an image. The image cannot be searched and cannot be edited.

Comment: Here's the simple answer without full derivation: in order for a Legendre transform $f(v)\rightarrow f(p)$ to be well-defined and invertible, you need $df/dv$ to be strictly concave in $v$.

For your second question, yes, time is a spectator variable in classical Hamiltonian dynamics.

Comment: Related : [A mathematically illogical argument in the derivation of Hamilton's equation in Goldstein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477111/a-mathematically-illogical-argument-in-the-derivation-of-hamiltons-equation-in/477873#477873).