# Is there a minimization principle for Hamiltonian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, action

Consider a point particle in $n$ dimensions.

For a Lagrangian $\mathcal L(\mathbf{q, \dot q}, t)$, we have that $\mathbf q(t)$ is a feasible trajectory for times $t_0<t<t_f$ iff it extremizes the integral
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal L(\mathbf q(t), \mathbf{\dot q}(t), t)\;dt.
$$
This is **equivalent** to saying that E-L equation
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\mathbf q} (\mathbf q(t), \mathbf{\dot q}(t), t) = 
\left[
\frac{d}{dt'} \frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\mathbf{\dot q}} (\mathbf q(t'), \mathbf{\dot q}(t'), t')
\right]_{t'=t}
$$
is satisfied.

Now, suppose that I give a Hamiltonian $H(\mathbf{q, p}, t)$ for the particle. Then, for a feasible phase space path $(\mathbf q(t), \mathbf p(t))$, there are Hamilton's equations
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial\mathbf q}(\mathbf q(t), \mathbf p(t), t) &= -\mathbf{\dot p}(t)\\
\frac{\partial H}{\partial\mathbf p}(\mathbf q(t), \mathbf p(t), t) &= \mathbf{\dot q}(t)
\end{align*}
which are satisfied. Now, I am aware that I can construct a Lagrangian (supplying$\frac{\partial H}{\partial\mathbf p}(\mathbf{q, p}, t)$ in Lagrangian's $\mathbf{\dot q}$) and this will give me a corresponding action integral, which will be extremized iff the the above Hamilton's equations are satisfied.

**Question:** Is there something that can be extremized in Hamiltonian formalism that is equivalent to Hamilton's equations, which *does **not** rely on defining Lagrangians*?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/580556/2451