# I don't get this "derivation" of canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, action

Given a transformation
$$(q, p, t)\to (Q(q, p, t), P(q, p, t), t),$$
the modified Hamiltonian, $K$ is related to the original one, $H$, as
$$H(q, p, t) = K(Q(q, p, t), P(q, p, t), t).$$
Now, what I've seen done everywhere$^1$ is to heuristically cook up some unjustified extremization principle for the Hamiltonians, demanding that
$$
\int (p_i\dot q_i-H(q, p, t))\; dt,\\
\int(P_i \dot Q_i-K(Q, P, t))\;dt
$$
be extremized. And this is followed by saying that a sufficient condition for them to lead to to the same equations of motion is that they differ by some total time derivative, and hence are born the generating functions.

**However, there are several things that I don't understand at all:**

1. The statement that seems to being (mis)used here is that if a trajectory $q(t)$ extremizes the integral $\int_{t_0}^{t_f} L(q(t), \dot q(t), t) dt$, then the same trajectory extremizes the integral if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}(q, t)\dot q+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(q, t)$ is added to $L(q, \dot q, t)$. **Question:** Is this justly used in the above? If so, how? There is no $p$ or $P$ in Lagrangian!
2. I don't even understand the claimed extremization principle. **Question:** How can one even go about extremizing this? Are we to perturb $(q(t), p(t))$ by **two** functions, $\delta q(t)$ and $\delta p(t)$? I'm familiar only with the action extremization principle that gives rise to E-L equations.

---

$^1$For example, [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-09-classical-mechanics-iii-fall-2014/lecture-notes/MIT8_09F14_Chapter_4.pdf) notes. (Section 4.1, Eq. (4.7-4.9).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let us start with OP's 2nd point. Yes, in [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) positions $q^i$ and momenta $p_i$ are $2n$ *independent* variables, where $i\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$. Let's introduce a collective notation
  $$(z^1,\ldots,z^{2n})~=~(q^1,\ldots,q^n,p_1,\ldots p_n).$$
- Concerning OP's 1st point, the main issue is that one should use the phase space variables $z^I$, not the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) variables $q^i$.

  - Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations for $z^I$, $I\in\{1,\ldots, 2n\}$, are precisely Hamilton's equations, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/580556/2451) Phys.SE post.
  - A total time derivative term does not change EL equation, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174137/2451) Phys.SE post (but now applied to $z$ rather than $q$).

Comment: So in point 1, $ L$ should be viewed as $ L(z, \dot z, t)$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll work out and will accept the answer if I get to the generating functions using this approach. Otherwise, I'll bother again. :)

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I got busy. But finally, your answer solved the thing!