# How to transform this function using Legendre transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, mathematics

$f(x,y)=x^3y^2$
the goal is the Legendre-transformed function: $g(x,u)=uy-f(x,y)$ where $u=\frac{∂ f}{∂ x}$ and $v=u=\frac{∂ f}{∂ y}$ where g(x,u) isn't explicitly dependent on y.

I derived $u=x^3y^2$. I heard that one now needs to reshape the equation to $y=\sqrt{(\frac{u}{3x^2})}$, but after that step I am not sure which variables are variables in the function $g(x,u)=uy-f(x,y)$ and which variables are "constants" and I am confused, why I need to reshape everything into the form y=... I thought I could just plug this into the equation and that's it.

I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Better for [math.se]?

Comment: Your initial statement looks quite confused. From the expression for g, it is clear that you have to use $u=\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{y}}$. Then you have to invert it, as you did, and substitute the resulting expression for $y(x,u)$ wherever you have $y$.

Comment: Related : [A mathematically illogical argument in the derivation of Hamilton's equation in Goldstein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477111/).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if $f$ is considered a Lagrangian, you see it as $f(x,v)=x^3 v^2$. Now the momentum can be calculated as $p=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=2x^3 v$. Then the Hamiltonian $g= pv - f(x,v)$ expressed as a function of $(x,p)$ by replacing $v$ as a function of $(x,p)$ would be $p \frac{p}{2x^3} - x^3  (\frac{p}{2x^3})^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: Is it then correct, that I get g(x,u)=$u\sqrt{\frac{u}{3x^2}}-\frac{xu}{3}$?

Comment: If you are using g=$uy-f$, you must use $u=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ instead of $u=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: I am confused as to why you patially derived f in respect to v and not in respect to y because in my lecture notes it says that $=\frac{∂}{∂}$ when we defined the Legendre transform

Comment: I was using $\partial f/\partial y$ but you were not doing that in your original post. $u=\frac{\partial x^3y^2}{\partial y}=2x^3y$, but you concluded $u=x^3 y^2$.