# A relationship between Lagrangian formalism and Hamiltonian formalism

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

In the Lagrangian formalism, The Lagrangian
$$L = T\text{(kinetic energy)} - V\text{(potential energy)}$$
The equations of motion for a given system is given by minimizing the action functional which is a integration of $L$.[1]

In the Hamiltonian formalism, The Hamiltonian
$$H  = T\text{(kinetic energy)} + V\text{(potential energy)}$$
The equations of motion for a given system are described by Hamilton’s equations which are differential equations of H.[1]

Said in an informal way: one formalism is 'subtract $(T-V)$' then 'integrate', the other formalism is 'add $(T+V)$' then 'differential'.

There is an interesting relationship between them: 'add' is the inverse of 'subtract', and 'differential' is the inverse of 'integrate'.

My question is : is there any deep understanding behind this relationship?

References:

1. No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics, JAKOB SCHWICHTENBERG, 2019. page 114-115.

Comment: I’m  it sure about the “integration” part: the Euler-Lagrange equations are differential equations, as are Hamilton’s equations.

Comment: The relationship between the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalisms is probably explained in any book that deals with them (including the one you cite).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4384/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41138/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Not strictly related : [A mathematically illogical argument in the derivation of Hamilton's equation in Goldstein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477111/a-mathematically-illogical-argument-in-the-derivation-of-hamiltons-equation-in/477873#477873).

Answer (score 4):

There are, of course, relationships between the two but not exactly the way you described. Also In general, it's not true,
$$\mathcal{L}=T-V \ \ \ \ \text{Not true in general}\ !!!$$
$$\mathcal{H}=T+V \ \ \ \ \text{Not true in general}\ !!!$$

---

The first relationship can be seen as Legendre transform

$$\mathcal{H}=p\dot{q}-\mathcal{L}$$
So both Hamiltonian and  Lagrangian follow the differential equations.

Another can be derived from the same
$$\delta\int\mathcal{L}dt=0$$
$$\delta \int (p\dot{q}-\mathcal{H})dt=0$$
In this respect, both follow the least action principle.