# Why are so many (all?) Key concepts in thermodynamics derived from a legendre transformation?

Tags: thermodynamics, lagrangian-formalism, potential, hamiltonian-formalism

Given a function $f(x,y)$, a legendre transform w.r.t. $x$ is $f^*(p,y)=p x - f(x,y) |_{p=\frac {\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}}$.

E.g. , the various free energies, enthalpy, etc are all legendre transformations of internal energy.

**It seems surpising to me that a multitidue (all?) of the important concepts in thermodynamics are derived from legendre transformations, and moreover that the legendre transformation is also the basis of hamiltonian fornalism. Why is this mathematical formalism so fundamental?** I would not have been able to know this just based on looking at the definition of the legendre transformation itself.

Comment: Some solid answers here to understand why this mathematical formalism is so fundamental: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4384/. Also, I would suggest reading  https://www.lpsm.paris/pageperso/lecomte/references2014/making-sense-of-legendre-transform.pdf.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) try to focus it, and only ask 1 subquestion. Right now it seems _too broad._