# Equivalence of Schrödinger operator formalism and Path Integral Formulations for Scalar Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, field-theory, schroedinger-equation, path-integral

I'm exploring the deep connections between different formulations of quantum field theories and have a specific question about the equivalence between the Schrödinger representation and the path integral representation for scalar field theory.

Since the path integral is derived from the Schrödinger equation, I recon that the relation should be bi-directional:

$$ \langle \phi_f |e^{-iHt/\hbar} | \phi_i \rangle = \int D[\phi] e^{iS[\phi]/\hbar} $$

Consider a free scalar field theory with the Lagrangian density:

$$ 
{\cal L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 
$$

From this, we can derive the corresponding Hamiltonian density:

$$ 
{\cal H} = \frac{1}{2} \pi^2 + \frac{1}{2} (\nabla \phi)^2 + \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 
$$

where $ \pi $ is the canonical momentum associated with $ \phi $.

Now, in the Schrödinger representation, we would describe the quantum field by a wavefunctional, $\Psi[\phi(x), t]$, evolving according to:

$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi[\phi(x), t] = H \Psi[\phi(x), t] $$

Given that the wavefunctionals in the Schrödinger picture are elements of a Fock space, is the Schrödinger representation using the derived Hamiltonian equivalent to the path integral representation?

Comment: You are asking for something like this question on [PI/canonical quantization equivalence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14481/226902) but for the Klein Gordon field, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Path Integral Quantization in Peskin and Schroeder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711542/2451)

Comment: That question and its (useful and closely related) answer do not say anything about the functional Schrödinger equation. I think the OP would like to know how to go from the functional Schrödinger equation to the PI and vice versa. Ofc, it is very likely to be a duplicate, but of another question. @Qmechanic

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional#Example:_scalar_field

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: This is mainly an exercise in transcribing the standard QM formulas into QFT.

1. The standard convention to write the wavefunctional is
   $$ \Psi[\phi,t] ~\equiv~  \langle \phi | \Psi(t)\rangle.   $$
2. Therefore OP's [TDSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)
   $$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}\Psi[\phi, t] ~=~ \hat{H} \Psi[\phi, t]$$
   in ket-form becomes
   $$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}| \Psi(t)\rangle  ~=~ \hat{H} | \Psi(t)\rangle.   $$
3. Here the Hamiltonian
   $$\hat{H}  ~=~\int d^3x~ \hat{\cal H} (x)$$
   is given in terms of the Hamiltonian density
   $$\hat{\cal H} (x) ~=~ \frac{1}{2}\left( \hat{\pi} (x)^2 +  (\nabla
   \hat{\phi} (x))^2 +  m^2 \hat{\phi} (x)^2 \right)+{\cal V}(\hat{\phi}(x)).$$
4. The [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)
   $$[\hat{\phi}(x), \hat{\pi}(y)]~=~i\hbar\hat{\bf 1}\delta^3(x\!-\!y)$$
   is the first principle of canonical quantization.
5. The Schrödinger representation reads
   $$\hat{\phi}(x)~=~\phi(x), \qquad
   \hat{\pi}(x)~=~\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}. $$
6. The time evolution operator is
   $$\hat{U}(t)~:=~\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}t\hat{H}\right). $$
7. The phase space path integral is derived from the operator formalism in the
   standard way by inserting infinitely many completeness relations
   $$\langle
   \phi_f|\exp\Big[-\frac{i}{\hbar}(t_f\!-\!t_i)\hat{H}\Big]|\phi_i\rangle
   ~=~\int_{\phi(\cdot,t_i)=\phi_i(\cdot)}^{\phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f(\cdot)}\,
   \mathcal{D}\phi\,\mathcal{D}\pi\,\exp\Big[\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}
   d^4x\,\big(\pi(x)\dot{\phi}(x)-{\cal H}(x) \big)\Big], $$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711542/2451) related
   Phys.SE post.